# Where is the XRCed GUI editor located which is distributed with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, xrc

I've been looking at the [XRCed tutorial on the wxPython website](https://wiki.wxpython.org/XRCed) and I'm trying to use it for my project. However the tutorial does not describe how to start the XRCed tool. No obvious files with the XRCed name seem to exist in the wxPython python install or the [wxWidgets/Phoenix github repo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix).

Can someone show me where this tool is located?

Comment: Most designers are capable of generating XRC content -- wxCrafter, wxFormBuilder and wxUiEditor all allow you to use a GUI to design your UI. For wxCrafter and wxFormBuilder you will need to cut and paste from their XRC tab into a file that you maintain. wxUiEditor will generate the file for you.

Comment: Thanks @Randolph I'll check these out.